# Rmagick histogram problems

Tags: ruby, rmagick

I'm having problems accessing the hash returned by color_histogram(). There are only black and white pixels in my image, and this is very frustrating.

When I do

```
puts hist.inspect() # returns "{red=0, green=0, blue=0, opacity=0=>779753, red=65535, green=65535, blue=65535, opacity=0=>6679}"
```

According to the documentation, the key is a Pixel object, so I construct

```
black = Magick::Pixel.from_color('black')
white = Magick::Pixel.from_color('white')

puts black.inspect # red=0, green=0, blue=0, opacity=0
puts white.inspect # red=65535, green=65535, blue=65535, opacity=0


puts hist[white] # raises exception: `[]': can't convert Magick::Pixel into Integer (TypeError)
```

Any ideas how I can access the histogram easily?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're changing `hist` somewhere between your [`color_histogram`](http://studio.imagemagick.org/RMagick/doc/image1.html#color_histogram) call and your `hist[white]`. This works for me with a simple black and white `bw.png`:

```
> i = Magick::Image.read('bw.png').first
=> bw.png PNG 100x100 100x100+0+0 DirectClass 8-bit 466b 
> h = i.color_histogram
=> {red=0, green=0, blue=0, opacity=0=>2342, red=65535, green=65535, blue=65535, opacity=0=>7658} 
> black = Magick::Pixel.from_color('black')
=> red=0, green=0, blue=0, opacity=0 
> h[black]
=> 2342
```

And you "can't convert Magick::Pixel into Integer (TypeError)" error is easily reproduced using an Array:

```
> a = [ ]
=> [] 
> a[black]
TypeError: can't convert Magick::Pixel into Integer
```

A Hash will never produce that TypeError from a simple access.